# MongoDb connection time in my Flutter app

Tags: mongodb, flutter, dart, mongodb-query, flutter-dependencies

I have used this package "**mongo_dart: ^0.8.2**" in my flutter app and connected my db with the following two lines:

```
var db = await Db.create("MY_URL");
await db.open();
```

These two lines are taking 10-15 seconds on average to execute which is huge time. User waits at the splash screen for this much time because I have to show data after fetching from mongo db on the homepage of my app. What should I do to make the initial connection faster?

I have tested adding my current IP address in Network Access which takes 5 seconds on average for connection but that is not the ultimate solution obviously.
Any help will be appreciated.